# How do I remove "Remember my changes" on tableau toolbar?

Tags: tableau-api, toolbar

I managed to remove "share" functionality using serverside script 
using 
    `tabadmin set vizqlserver.showshare false`

Manual:
http://downloads.tableausoftware.com/quickstart/server-guides/en-us/server_admin7.0.pdf

Comment: Never mind. Resolved it.

http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v7.0/server/en-us/embed_list.htm#id6f53a3c4-4911-44b1-8290-4efb9313f532

First item on the list. set custom views to no. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:customViews=n` on your URL or

```
<parameter name="customViews" value="n" />
```

in your object definition will also get you there without having to turn things off globally.